# How positive integers are stored in computer memory? Their 2's complement is stored as for negative integers in memory or their binary equivalent?

Tags: c, memory, integer, unsigned, signed

For negative integers their 2's complement is stored in memory. I'm confused with positive integers. They are stored directly in binary format or they are also stored in 2's complement.Please mention for both signed and unsigned.

Comment: `They are stored directly in binary format or they are also stored in 2's complement` but... it's the same.

Comment: See [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), an integer in two's complement can hold positive and negative values.

Answer (score 0):

Two's complement is used in computing as a form of signed binary representation.

One bit is saved for that purpose. So a positive number and a negative one are stored exactly the same in memory, just a bit indicates if it is positive or not.

Positive 127 in memory:
`127 -> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1`

Negative 127 in memory:
`-127 -> 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1`

As you can see if the MSB (Most Significant Byte) contains 1 it means it is negative, all the bytes are inverted and the whole number is incremented in one.